# UICollectionView contentOffset wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` set up inside a normal `UIViewController`, the view is supposed to show two different types of data/cells, based on a property toggled by a button. The data source always remains the same, it just gets repopulated on each button tap.

Whenever the button action is triggered, it empties and refills the main data source array and calls `-reloadData` on the collection view. This works fine and there is no unexpected behaviour there.

Now the issue is, the scroll position, a.k.a. the `contentOffset`, remains the same after changing the filter. So say the collection view would be showing cells of type `A`, I would start scrolling rapidly, tap the button, and see the cells change to type `B` but still keep scrolling. The user would have to repeatedly scroll back to their last position, if they can remember it.

I've attempted to solve this by having a `scrollPositions` `NSMutableDictionary` as a property in my view controller. The keys represent the filter type (`A` or `B`), and the values represent the y coordinate of the current content offset (this is a vertically-scrolled collection view).

The problem I've encountered is that even though this seems to work to some degree, the `contentOffset` property seems to randomly be off by a certain amount of pixels, sometimes it's just a dozen or so, and sometimes it's half a screen's worth.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Capturing `bounds` instead
- Adjusting `edgesForExtendedLayout`
- Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`
- Remembering the currently visible index path, but this seems to be incorrect at times as well
- Calling `-invalidateLayout` on the collection view and `-layoutIfNeeded` on the parent view before capturing the offset and before restoring it
- Straight up switching to a `UIPageViewController` and having a `UIViewController` containing a `UICollectionView` for each different filter, but that brought on a whole other host of problems.

But unfortunately, no matter what I try, I always end up with the same results. When returning to the previously set filter, it does change back to the previously-captured offset, which is almost where I left off, but not quite. I'm quite honestly at my wits' end here, anyone have any more suggestions?

**ALSO**, if it matters this is all set up with AutoLayout, and have had some bad experiences with vanilla `UIScrollView`s and AutoLayout in the past. So maybe some of the issues may have been inherited?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with `NSMutableDictionary` should work, just remember to stop the scrolling when changing filter, so you can have the most accuracy possible on the offset. To stop the current scrolling:

```
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Then enable it back.

```
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should've specified that I have tried disabling scrolling as well. Also waiting a few seconds before changing the filter in the hopes that the collection view can internally resolve its logic and update its offset property. The scenario I proposed where the user switches tabs while scrolling is not the crux of this issue. Rather, the inaccuracy of the `contentOffset` property.